# Why android app crashes immediately after launch, when included firebase references?

Tags: android, crash

I've seen similar questions here but none of them solved my problem. Just after adding the line  "`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'`" in the app dependencies my app crashes withing seconds after showing the main activity. When I comment out the line, the app working without problem. I haven't written any firebase code yet and just added the reference.

I'm using `Android studio 3.4.1,` `Gradle plugin 3.4.1`, `Gradle 5.1.1`, Embeded JDK with Android studio.

I tried invalidating cash and restart the studio, syncing gradle without result.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.ourshops.shops.ourshops"
    minSdkVersion 28
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
  'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'






buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {

    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
}
```

Can anyone point me in right direction to solve this problem and run firebase properly?

Comment: If you app is crashing, you should paste your error log

Comment: it seems that it's not the issue, run you app and find some red colored text on LogCat, you can filter by Errors

Comment: 2019-06-20 08:03:52.369 13119-13119/com.ourshops.shops.ourshops E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.ourshops.shops.ourshops, PID: 13119
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/util/ArrayMap;
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.<clinit>(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.1.0:154)